# Селектор JQuery для конкретной ячейки

Tags: javascript, ajax

Добрый день.

У нас есть таблица с 10 колонками.  в последней - картинка с функцией удаления строки (код ниже). в первой колонке в скрытом поле содержится abn_id.
Я получаю ячейку таблицы (<td align="left" >...3 контрола...</td>), по которой клацнули удаление (10ая строка, первая, девятая, не важно)

Выглядит это так:

```
  function DeleteContact(Contr) {
        var EditSpan = $(Contr).parent();
        var AllRows = EditSpan.parent().prevAll();
        var a = AllRows[AllRows.length-1];
...
}
```

Contr - это контроль, картинка, на которую нажали и вызвалась функция
**" AllRows[AllRows.length-1] "** - тут находится контроль ячейка таблицы с input hidden, который мне нужно вытянуть. я знаю его ИД

ВОПРОС: подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу вытянуть только 1 контрол из ячейки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в хроме, ПКМ на нужный элемент -> Просмотр кода элемента,   затем выбираете там элемент, ПКМ на нем и copy CSS path,   должно получится что-то типо: #CARight > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > p:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2), ну и потом этот адрес в параметр jq

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Завтра же попробую на работе)